# Pushing local maven repos to server

Tags: java, maven-3, nexus

I am setting up a maven repository for my workplace. The main reason for setting up a new private repository is that, our original nexus repo is hidden behind a VPN network. So anyone who wished to pull the dependencies. He needs to have a VPN connection in the working machine. Goal is to make the VPN secured artefacts under the newly created repo to make it available for CI pipeline.

Right now I am doing it as below, listing all the dependencies using following command:

```
mvn -Dmdep.copyPom=true dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Which send all the jars under target/dependency.

And then I using the following maven command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
```

Which pushes all the dependencies in my newly created nexus, issue is that during setting deploy-file command I am passing a group id which is a generic one. And all the jars are pushed under that groupid. Which is different than my local name namespace/groupid, as different packages are under different group id and pushing all of them under a same group id makes them unusable as it messes with the namespace.

I am new to maven, and the approach I took feels like a hack. Can I use maven native functionality to solve the problem? What would be the standard way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Nexus has a concept of proxy repositories , for the open source dependencies, you can create proxy repository to mirror the maven central repo and provide in the proxy information is maven settings and run a mvn install, during the resource generation phase of maven the nexus will automatically pull artifacts from the central repo and cache them in your proxy repository for future use.